# Display Image Result of API to WEB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

The retrieval and image conversion from byte to image is working great

API CODE:

```
[HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage MemberImage(string employeeId)
        {
            IMemberProcedures storedProcedure = new StoredProcedure();
            IValidation validation = new CommonRepository();
            RequestModel request = SQL.Read(out List<MemberDetail> members, storedProcedure.SAMPLESTOREDPROCEDURE("::1", employeeId));
            byte[] imgData = members[0].Picture;
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgData);
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new StreamContent(ms);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new
            MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
            return response;
        }
```

Trying this in postman returns a fully converted image

Now I wanted to display that image to my Web and this is what I have tried;

WEB CODE:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MemberImage(string id)
        {
            IGetInterface Ip = new IpHelper();
            HttpResponseMessage image = API.GetResponse($"api/QMS/MemberImage?employeeId={id}");
            var foo = image.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            return File(Enumerable.Range(0, foo.Length)
                             .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                             .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(foo.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                             .ToArray(), "image/png");
        }
```

This triggers an error of Unsupported Media and I dont think I am doing the right way of displaying the image from web controller to my view.

**Is there any other way on displaying image result of API to WEB?**

Comment: I don't know what you're doing here on the last line.

Comment: @T.S. me either sir I am so lost I just showed what I've tried but what I really wanted is different approach on how to display the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after several retries I got it working by using `ReadAsByteArrayAsync()`.

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult MemberImage(string id)
        {
            IGetInterface Ip = new IpHelper();
            HttpResponseMessage image = API.GetResponse($"api/QMS/MemberImage?employeeId={id}");
            byte[] foo = image.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
            return File(foo, "image/png");

        }
```

Display it to view by doing this;

`<img src='@Url.Action("MemberImage", new { id = Model.Member.EmployeeNumber })'>`